# Geopandas Python IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 0

Tags: python, geopandas

I have the following code adapted from the GeoPandas website for sampling raster data using point locations:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from pathlib import Path

# Load point shapefile
pipecr_no = gpd.read_file(data_folder / "Pipeline Crossings.shp")

# Load raster for distance to road access point
cr4_file = data_folder / "acc_fuzz_base.rst"                          
cr4 = rasterio.open(cr4_file)    

# Points tu use for sampling raster
pts = pipecr_no
    
# Obtain coordinates list of points
coord_list = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(pts['geometry'].x, pts['geometry'].y)]
    
# Sample the raster at every point location and store values in DataFrame
pts['value'] = [x for x in cr4.sample(coord_list)]
```

I get the following error:

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_63376\451614584.py in <module>
      5 
      6 # Sample the raster at every point location and store values in DataFrame
----> 7 pts['value'] = [x for x in cr4.sample(coord_list)]

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_63376\451614584.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      5 
      6 # Sample the raster at every point location and store values in DataFrame
----> 7 pts['value'] = [x for x in cr4.sample(coord_list)]

~\anaconda3\envs\Sensi_Anly\lib\site-packages\rasterio\sample.py in sample_gen(dataset, xy, indexes)
     21             window = Window(col_off, row_off, 1, 1)
     22             data = read(indexes, window=window, masked=False)
---> 23             yield data[:, 0, 0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 0
```

The following is some further information about the code:

**pipecr_no** is a shapefile with the following attribute table:

```
    pipecr_no   geometry
0   1   POINT (390211.518 6035950.409)
1   2   POINT (393460.141 6036296.642)
2   3   POINT (392976.790 6036438.689)
3   4   POINT (393564.784 6036626.931)
4   5   POINT (393546.126 6036695.471)
5   6   POINT (393372.126 6040161.557)
6   7   POINT (396154.967 6035344.027)
7   8   POINT (393679.240 6036264.372)
8   9   POINT (393655.288 6041201.561)
9   10  POINT (396495.196 6032373.055)
10  11  POINT (398029.319 6035455.204)
11  12  POINT (400866.149 6036504.876)
```

**cr4** is a raster

Comment: It may help your debugging to turn your list comprehensions into for loops, and add some investigative print statements. The shape of your intermediate arrays is not what the function call is expecting.

Comment: also, in the future please [format](/help/formatting) your error as a code block rather than a quotation - thanks!

Comment: and can you define all variables, such as `cr4`? what is it? Ideally, please try to create a [mre], or at least fully define the pieces of code we're looking at. thanks!

Comment: what is `cr4` a **rasterio** array?

Comment: @Rob Raymond yes, cr4 is a rasterio raster array.   Maybe that is my problem; the dimensions of the pts table and the array not lining up?